# How to Date picker + show date in a button?android

Tags: android, layout, button, datepicker, textview

I want to have in my activity a button that shows default the current date as a button title and when i click the button to show a date picker dialog and shown the new pick as button title.

How can i achieve that?Any better idea?Is better to do this with EditText for being easier fro the user that he can change the date?

Comment: follow this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have attached code here for both time and date, use this as per your requirements.
here intend of txtdate and txtTime youcan set it on button text.

```
private static final int DIALOG_DATE = 1;
         private static final int DIALOG_TIME = 2;    


private Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
     private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
             "MMMM dd yyyy");
     private SimpleDateFormat timeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
             "hh:mm a");


                 txtstdate.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));   
  txtAddtime.setText(timeFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));


@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case DIALOG_DATE:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
                {
                    dateTime.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    txtstdate.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
                    txtAdddate.setText(dateFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
                }
            }, dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
               dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
               dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        case DIALOG_TIME:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, new OnTimeSetListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                        int minute)
                {
                    dateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                    dateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                    txtsttime.setText(timeFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
                    txtAddtime.setText(timeFormatter.format(dateTime.getTime()));
                }
            }, dateTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
               dateTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE), false);

        }
        return null;
    }


}

**Call Dialog:**
```

Call This method on button click event.

```
showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);

showDialog(DIALOG_TIME);
```

Visit For More Ref: http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/search/label/Date%20and%20time%20Dialog.
http://hasmukhbhadani.blogspot.in/search/label/DatePickerSlider%20in%20android.